# Update / Refresh Listview From Custom Adapter Dialog Possitive Button After Updating Sqlite Database

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite, android-adapter

I have a list view that gets populated from a database. On the same activity I also have an EditTExt and an Add Category Button above the listview.

### EditText      | Add Category

Category Name1 | Edit Button | Delete Button
Category Name2 | Edit Button | Delete Button
Category Name3 | Edit Button | Delete Button

1. If I Add Category, the listview updates.
2. If I click on Delete, Opens Up Dialog (Are You Sure?), when you click yes it deletes it from the database and then updates the listview with the row deleted.
3. If I click the edit button (which is in the custom adapter for the listview layout), it opens up the dialog and shows an edittext with the category name and you can change it and when you click on the save button it saves it to the database but **DOES NOT** update the listview.

So I solved the issue instead of trying to repoll the database to update the listview again, I grabbed the position and the edittext for the category of that row and updated it that way.

Being only 1 item can be edited at a time I figured no big deal until I ran into another issue by using this work around.  And that is:

If you click on Edit Button For Category Name1 and in the dialog you rename it to Meaningful Category Name.  It updates the database, it is reflected in the listview right away, but when you delete the item before doing anything else when I send the message to a different listview to let me know that it was deleted, it reflects the original category name and not the edited one.

Now the work around for this is that when I want to delete it, instead of relying on the category name from the listview, get the category name from the database before it's deleted, then delete it and then send the message with the category name from the database.

What I would really like instead of using the 2 workarounds is the following flow:

Activity Loads With Custom Listview ->  Click on Edit -> Dialog Edit Opens From Custom Adapter -> Click on Save Button -> Database is updated. -> Listview is updated / refreshed.

I have it all working with the exception of Listview is updated / refreshed.

I have searched high and low and can find all kinds of things that you can do to refresh listview, but none of them work and none of them are for Database update from within a dialog in the custom adapter.

I can post code, but I thought this is pretty much straight forward.  If not I will gladly post code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using a CursorAdapter which eliminates the need for an intermediate Array and refreshing is a breeze.

Here's an example, that uses the SimpleCursorAdapter, that does all but edit (however you may well want a Custom Cursor Adapter). However the refresh aspect is no different bar the specific adapter type.

The layout **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/categoryname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addcategorybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD CATEGORY"
        >
    </Button>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categorylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

- i.e. EditText, Add Button and ListView

The Database Helper **DBHelper**

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "category.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TB_CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String COl_ID_CATEGORY = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COl_CATEGORYNAME_CATEGORY = "category_name";

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static volatile DBHelper instance;

    private DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_CATEGORY + "(" +
                COl_ID_CATEGORY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
                "," + COl_CATEGORYNAME_CATEGORY + " TEXT UNIQUE " +
                ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insertCategory(String categoryName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_CATEGORYNAME_CATEGORY,categoryName);
        return db.insert(TB_CATEGORY,null,cv);
    }

    public int deleteCategory(long id) {
        return db.delete(TB_CATEGORY,COl_ID_CATEGORY + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }

    public int deleteCategory(String categoryName) {
        return db.delete(TB_CATEGORY,COl_CATEGORYNAME_CATEGORY + "=?",new String[]{categoryName});
    }

    public int updateCategory(Long id, String categoryName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_CATEGORYNAME_CATEGORY,categoryName);
        return db.update(TB_CATEGORY,cv,COl_ID_CATEGORY+"=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }

    public int updateCategory(String oldCatgeoryName, String newCategoryName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_CATEGORYNAME_CATEGORY,newCategoryName);
        return db.update(TB_CATEGORY,cv,COl_CATEGORYNAME_CATEGORY + "=?",new String[]{oldCatgeoryName});
    }

    public Cursor getCategories() {
        return db.query(TB_CATEGORY,null,null,null,null,null,COl_CATEGORYNAME_CATEGORY + " ASC");
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** Cursor adapters expect(must have) a column named **_id** (hence BaseColumns._ID) and that column should be a unique integer that identiofies the row. Most often an alias of the rowid column aka column is defined using `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (with or without AUTOINCREMENT (without is more efficient, with is rarely required so best not used)).
- As you can see simple two column table _id and categoryname. methods to add, update, insert, delete and extract all rows (as a Cursor) have been added.

The Activity **MainActivity** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText categoryName;
    Button addCategory;
    ListView categoryList;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    DBHelper db;
    Cursor csr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        categoryName = this.findViewById(R.id.categoryname);
        addCategory = this.findViewById(R.id.addcategorybutton);
        categoryList = this.findViewById(R.id.categorylist);
        db = DBHelper.getInstance(this);
        setupAddCategoryButton();
        setOrRefreshCategoryListView();
    }


    public void setOrRefreshCategoryListView() {
        csr = db.getCategories();
        if (sca == null) {
            sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    csr, //<<<<<<<< The Cursor
                    new String[]{DBHelper.COl_CATEGORYNAME_CATEGORY}, //<<<<<<<< The list of columns to be displayed
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, //<<<<<<<< The corresponding view id's in the layout that is to display the data from the column
                    0
            );
            categoryList.setAdapter(sca);
            categoryList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    DBHelper dbx = DBHelper.getInstance(view.getContext());
                    if (dbx.deleteCategory(l) > 0) {
                        setOrRefreshCategoryListView();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            sca.swapCursor(csr);
        }
    }

    public void setupAddCategoryButton() {
        addCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (categoryName.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    if (db.insertCategory(categoryName.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                        setOrRefreshCategoryListView();
                    }
                    categoryName.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- See the `setOrRefreshCategoryListView`, all that is needed to refresh (and initially setup the ListView) is done in here. You just have to call the method.

When the above is run. Categories can be added by entering text and then clicking the ADD CATEGORY button. Categories can be deleted by long clicking a Category.

**Result**

After adding a few categories (1-3) and just before adding a 4th :-

[image]

Click on Add :-

[image]

Long Click Category 2 :-

[image]

**Additional re comment**

> I was just hiping that there was a way to refresh the listview from within the custom adapter itself after the update from the alertdialog.

perhaps consider the following which shows both refresh from within the adapter (i.e. hot DLT button and item is deleted and refreshed)

and also from the invoking activity via the EDIT button (doesn't edit just toasts).

First the layout used for the CustomAdapter

- subclass of CursorAdapter which I would still recommend over ArrayAdapter (i.e. CursorAdapter exists for a reason).

  ```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6">
        </TextView>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/categoryedit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="EDIT"
            android:onClick="onClickEditCategoryButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/categorydelete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="DLT"
            >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
  ```
- **NOTE** the EDIT button has onCLick specified so onClicklistener code is coded on your behalf.

**DBHelper** is unchanged from above.

**MainActivity** is now :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText categoryName;
    Button addCategory;
    ListView categoryList;
    CustomAdapter ca;
    DBHelper db;
    Cursor csr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        categoryName = this.findViewById(R.id.categoryname);
        addCategory = this.findViewById(R.id.addcategorybutton);
        categoryList = this.findViewById(R.id.categorylist);
        db = DBHelper.getInstance(this);
        setupAddCategoryButton();
        setOrRefreshCustomCategoryListView();
    }

    public void setOrRefreshCustomCategoryListView() {
        csr = db.getCategories();
        if (ca == null) {
            ca = new CustomAdapter(this,csr);
            categoryList.setAdapter(ca);
        } else {
            ca.swapCursor(csr);
        }
    }

    public void onClickEditCategoryButton(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.categoryedit: {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked Edit for Category with ID of " + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setOrRefreshCustomCategoryListView();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public void setupAddCategoryButton() {
        addCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (categoryName.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    if (db.insertCategory(categoryName.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                        setOrRefreshCustomCategoryListView();
                    }
                    categoryName.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Last the **CustomAdapter** :-

```
class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    CustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor csr) {
        super(context,csr, android.widget.CursorAdapter.IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor csr, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.categorylist,parent,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor csr) {
        TextView categoryName = view.findViewById(R.id.categoryname);
        categoryName.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COl_CATEGORYNAME_CATEGORY)));
        // Set Button tags with id of current row
        // NOTE button onClick listener set in layout
        String id = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COl_ID_CATEGORY));
        view.findViewById(R.id.categoryedit).setTag(id);
        view.findViewById(R.id.categorydelete).setTag(id);
        view.findViewById(R.id.categorydelete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"You Clicked Delete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                DBHelper.getInstance(context).deleteCategory(Long.parseLong(view.getTag().toString()));
                refreshListView(context);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public void refreshListView(Context context) {
        this.swapCursor(DBHelper.getInstance(context).getCategories());
    }
}
```

**result**

Looks like this now (clicking Edit toasts (via activity), clicking DLT deletes (via adapter))
[image]

Comment: I don't have an issue with adding only when editing.

Comment: I was half asleep when I seen this so I am going to try this again.  I am using a customadapter for a custom listview.  This is where the problem lies.  because the database UPDATE is being done from the customadapter in the dialog.  I only see 2 possible solutions to get the results I am looking for: The first is when it goes to the message activity to poll the database for the item that was updated, or 2 force a refresh by using intent and put extra and then in the message activity check the getextras and depending on data do what I need it to do.  either way will work.

Comment: I was just hiping that there was a way to refresh the listview from within the custom adapter itself after the update from the alertdialog.

Comment: @ShawnMulligan added to question showing delete (button in the list) and refresh via adapter . The EDIT button is handled in the activity to just show an alternative, all it does is toast but it does refresh the ListView.

Comment: Okay so I am not quite sure where the miscommunication is but let's try this again.  I load the activity with a listview.  The listview is custom and therefore is loaded from the CustomAdapter.  When the listview loads it shows the category name, an edit button and a delete button.  when you click on the edit button which we are still in the custom adapter because of the custom listview, it opens up a Dialog with an edittext and save or cancel.  Still in the custom adapter when you click save, it saves it to the database, but does not refresh the custom listview from the custom adapter.